# Do not allow passwords to be saved in Remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, rdp

Greeting,
I have a PC with Windows 7 home edition. As known, Windows 7 home edition has no Group Policy setting option. I want to disable saving password and user name option in  Remote desktop connection and I know how to do it with gpedit.msc but now without having this option how can I  disable saving password and user name option in  Remote desktop connection?

by the way, I'm using rdp file to connect.
Please advice.

Regards,

Comment: Greetings. As known, all GPO Policies are really just registry settings, so the effects of GPO can be replicated by manipulating the registry. With some time an effort you can even open the adm and admx files in a text editor and read the exact keys for any particular GPO setting you'd like to replicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this works on the home edition, but this is what the policy effectively does:

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\Terminal Services`
3. Create or edit a DWORD named `DisablePasswordSaving` and set the value
   to 1 (any non-zero value should do)

If you just want to apply this to a single user and not for all users, make this change to the same key in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

Comment: Or [edit the Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791914.aspx)

Comment: @vladr The question begs for a non-GPO solution, thus "this is what the policy effectively does:"